# Using one Resources.resw file for two or more projects in the same solution

Tags: localization, windows-runtime

So as the title states it, I'm trying to use one Resource.resw file to get string for two projects that exist in the same solution. On the code behind I can use the resource manager correctly, but on XAML, using the `x:uid` to automatically get the resource (like it's explain in [this example](http://www.neovelop.com/blog/localizing-windows-8-metro-xaml-applications)) does not work from the project that doesn't have the `Resources.resw` file.

Is there any setting I'm missing so XAML can find the Resources.resw automatically. Of course the reason I'm trying to do this is to avoid redundancy - we definitely don't want two Resources files that contain the same strings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone from our team found the solution, basically we have to state the path to the Resource file in the `x:Uid` property:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="/Errors/AlreadyRegistered"></TextBlock>
```

It's explained in [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965323%28v=win.10%29).